# Как сделать так, чтобы WHERE применялся при отборе только определенных полей?

Tags: mysql

```
    SELECT 
        granule_list.brand_id,
        granule_list.type,
        AVG(price_table.price), 
        AVG(price_table.percent_diff)  
    FROM 
        granule_list, price_table  
    WHERE 
       (price_table.brand_id=granule_list.brand_id)
    GROUP BY 
        granule_list.type
```

Нужно, чтобы WHERE работал только для `AVG(price_table.price)` и `AVG(price_table.percent_diff)`
Дело в том, что строки в таблице price_list с полем brand_id равным полю brand_id в таблице granule_list  может не существовать. Но это не значит, что строку выводить не надо, нужно вывести хотя бы поля  granule_list.brand_id,   granule_list.type и оставить пустыми        AVG(price_table.price) AVG(price_table.percent_diff).  А мой код вообще не выводит такую строку.

Comment: *может не существовать* — а по какому критерию тогда нужно связывать таблицы? я не про техническую, а про логическую сторону такого связывания.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

То, что вы показали через WHERE это внутреннее соединение (INNER JOIN), а для вывода записей при отсутствующих связях требуется внешнее (LEFT OUTER JOIN, RIGHT OUTER JOIN). AVG() как и другие агрегатные функции будет игнорировать null значения.

```
SELECT 
    granule_list.brand_id,
    granule_list.type,
    AVG(price_table.price), 
    AVG(price_table.percent_diff)  
FROM 
    granule_list LEFT JOIN price_table ON (price_table.brand_id=granule_list.brand_id)
GROUP BY 
    granule_list.type
```